# struct.error: argument for's' must be a bytes object

Tags: python, sockets, object, byte, ip-address

By using this code:

```
import socket, struct, fcntl

SIOCSIFADDR = 0x8916

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

def setIpAddr(iface, ip): 
    bin_ip = socket.inet_aton(ip)
    ifreq = struct.pack('16sH2s4s8s', iface, socket.AF_INET, '\x00'*2, bin_ip,'\x00'*8)
    fcntl.ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFADDR, ifreq)

setIpAddr('em1', '192.168.0.1')
```

I receive

> "struct.error: argument for's' must be a bytes object"

Which object is meant here?

Comment: can you format your code? given that this is python and formatting is essential

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepend you strings with `b` to make them bytes like:

```
ifreq = struct.pack('16sH2s4s8s', iface, socket.AF_INET, b'\x00' * 2, bin_ip, b'\x00' * 8)

setIpAddr(b'em1', '192.168.0.1')
```

Comment: That was the fault. Thanks Stephen.

Comment: But now I get:
Traceback(most recent call last):
...in<module> setIPAddr (DecUserIntFace,'192.168.0.1')
..in setIPAddr 
fcntl.ioctl(sock,SIOCSIFADDR,ifreq)
PermissionError:[errno 1] operation not permitted

Comment: Probably need to be root (sudo)